# How to force a file to open via a bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line, command

**Why can I not get this bash command to not work correctly?**

As of now I am using this to open files in Sublime Text

```
open -a Sublime\ Text path/to/file_directory/file_name.php     (doesn't have to be php)
```

This works on most files but doesn't work on some files.

AKA:

- .htaccess
- some_file (without .txt, .php or any other ending to it)
- some_file.txt

Answer (score 1):

In OS X, each file type (identified by the file name extension, e.g. `.txt` or `.php`) has a default program associated with it, that is used to open files of this kind. It seems like you do not have any program associated with `.txt` or `.htaccess` files.

[Here](http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/25/change-file-associations-in-mac-os-x/) it is explained how to change file associations.

Comment: I already have sublime text set up as the default application to open the files.  However this is a valid reason why it might not work.  I hit that step before posting this.  I should've mentioned it above.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I fixed the problem.  Gosh.. I hate how some mistakes can be so stupid.

Comment: Please post your solution in case someone else faces the same stupidity :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically I am using the application Alfred to execute tasks to speed up my workflow.

I extended an alfred workflow that originally was supposed to show your recent downloads directory, but I changed this to show my developer notes directory.  This is useful because then I can just open alfred with

```
⌘ space
```

and then it will type

```
dn
```

and it will pull in all the files from my Developer Notes directory.  My problem was I wanted to just hit **enter** to open it correctly in Sublime Text.  My stupid error was I didn't switch the script format from

```
/usr/bin/php    ==back to==>     /bin/bash
```

This is the reason why it wasn't working.  Not any syntactical errors.  Just a silly stupid overlooked error.   I found it though!  Just remember, if you're building alfred workflows, don't forget to switch the script filter language.

Comment: Nevertheless it's more convenient to use the wrapper provided by ST. That's what it is for - opening files from the command line. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case just use

```
subl path/to/file
```

in order to open files with Sublime Text from the command line. Sublime Text provides a command line wrapper.
Please have a look at the [documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

*From the OS X man page for* `open`:

```
-t  Causes the file to be opened with the default text editor, as determined via LaunchServices
```

So all you need to do is add the following line to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

```
    EDITOR="/bin/local/subl -nw"
```

or if you have Sublime Text installed in the usual location,

```
    EDITOR="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text -nw"
```

Then from a command line or script, you can run

```
    open -t file_name
```